# Missing separator in my Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

This is my structure:

- Makefile
- src/main.cpp
- include/xml.hpp

My Makefile looks like this:

```
# Define compiler: gcc for C program, define as g++ for C++
CC = g++

# Compiler flags:
#  -g    adds debugging information to the executable file
#  -Wall turns on most, but not all, compiler warnings
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall

# Build target executable:
TARGET = main

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(TARGET).c
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c

clean:
  $(RM) $(TARGET)
```

The error I get is this:

```
15 *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I copied this code from a tutorial so I'm not sure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Are the spaces before `$(CC)` and `$(RM)` a single tab character? or 2 spaces?

Comment: General advice: it is always good idea to enable "Show whitespaces" option in your text editor

Comment: Did you even try to search for "makefile missing separator" before asking this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using spaces instead of tabs.

The parser doesn't like that.